# How to check Alfresco migration was done correctly?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I can practice Alfresco migration or version up with DB backup and file & index transition.

It might be successful because every documents and folders works as ever as long as I look into,
but I can still want to check all stuffs are correctly and exhaustively migrated in terms of Alfresco repository just for confirmation.

Anyone knows such tools like checking the number of documents in the repository , or other useful tools/dashlets.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the the Lucene index with: [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/)
it's a Java tool that lets you lurk inside a Lucene index, so you could make a comparison between the old and the new repository.
For the db you could use any query browser you find online, like PGadmin for PostgreSQL, to connect to the new Alfresco db and compare it to the old one. You should look for the number of nodes in the repo, that is stored inside the alf_node table of the Alfresco db.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if upgrade was successfull you need to check catalina.out, alfresco.log. There you find comments to all steps of the upgrade and reports are generated in /temp/Alfresco/*.txt for the database schema upgrade steps. Please read/check these logs carefully. There are no tools available which states: Repository is migrated succesfull. If you don't care and keep problems your system may work but you may have trouble with future upgrades.